# Django: Invalid block tag 'form.username'

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create a login page.

Here's (part of) my *urls.py* file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', main_page),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
```

And here's the template for my login page (*registration/login.html*):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>User Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>username and password don't match.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
        <p>
            <label for="id_username">Username:</label> 
                    {% form.username %}
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_password">Password:</label> 
                    {% form.password %}
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" /> 
            <input type="submit" name="login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start the application and go to *login.html* I receive the following error message:

> **TemplateSyntaxError at /login/**
>
> Invalid block tag: 'form.username'

I don't understand what went wrong. As far as I know, the *login view* is supposed to load this template and pass the `form` object. When printed, the `form.username` attribute is supposed to generate HTML code for the username text field. Why doesn't that happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`form` is a context variable, not a template tag. So access it via `{{ form }}` or `{{ form.username }}`!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

There was a confusion between `{% ... %}` and `{{ ... }}`.

`{{ variable name }}`

`{% command %}`

It's supposed to be `{{ form.username }}` and `{{ form.password }}`

instead of `{% form.username %}` and `{% form.password %}`.